# problems with paragraphs in apa6 class

Tags: apa6

I'm writing a document with the apa6-class. Unfortunately, the paragraphs in one section are different (bigger) than the other ones. The indentation is fine but the space is not double-spaced like in the rest of the document. I didn't change any of the settings. Therefore I also can't post a simple example reproducing the error. Here's my preamble:

```
    \documentclass[man,a4paper,floatsintext]{apa6}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nty,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{super.bib}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{fancyref}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
```

Anyone with the same problem? I'm using TeX-Live on Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I doubt we can help much just given that information, please try to follow the [steps to make a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225) start with your document and remove stuff until you just have one good paragraph and one bad one, then post the result.

Comment: I figured it out: It's because of the `floatsintext` option. When I don't use it, all paragraphs are ok.

Comment: OK I think we'll close the question as "too localised" glad you got it working.

Comment: Well, I know where the problem lies, but I don't know how to solve it. Anyway, we can close it

Comment: Oh sorry If you still have a problem then we shouldn't close. Edit your question to be a complete document, remove any unneeded packages and add whatever option required to cause the problem then someone can answer.

Comment: @Macs If you can't show how to reproduce the problem, it's very difficult to pinpoint its cause.